# What does "get in" mean?

Tags: yesterday-2019

Jed Malik found his pickle while searching.
Meanwhile Ed Sheeran asking Jack for European 
leg of the tour:

> Jed Malik (says to Ed Sheeran): **Get in**.

What does "get in" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Get in!" or "Get in there!" is British slang used as to celebrate a good result for someone else - probably startng from soccer fans and/or players celebrating a hard won goal.

Jed is expressing his excitement at Jack being asked on the tour.

Comment: Apparently it's an expression from the 1920's. Young men would exhort each other to get in(to a conversation with a young lady)